# How to interpret moderation effect on curvilinear relationship?

Tags: regression, interaction, fixed-effects-model

I have run a fixed regression analysis for panel data, however I am having trouble interpreting my results and my regression table. In my first hypothesis I argue for a inversed U-shaped relationship between my IV and DV. In my second hypothesis I argue for a positive moderation effect and in my third hypothesis I argue for a negative moderation effect. How should I interpret this?

[image: Regression table and plots]

Comment: I think that part of your problem is that you have imposed a strict quadratic form on `APD` in your model. That might force your model into a shape that doesn't correctly represent the true association between `APD` and your outcome measure. Flexible spline fits of continuous predictors are generally better and more reliable. Try that. Also, it's not completely clear what you are trying to accomplish with the various submodels (Models 1 through 4) of your complete Model 5. Please edit the question to provide more details about what you are trying to accomplish that way.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I will look into using a flexible spline. However, if I would want to interpret the current data. How should I interpret this? e.g. Can I say that for example that while I expected KB to positively moderate the main relationship, it actually negatively moderates the main relationship (because the graph is flattened as opposed to steepened?) In addition, can I say therefore that high KB leads to higher innovation performance (DV)?

Comment: Another difficulty is that you have separate interaction terms for the linear and quadratic components of `APD`: and their estimated coefficients have opposite signs! So it's not really clear how to interpret the direction of the moderation in that case, when you have restricted the association between `APD` and your RV to be strictly quadratic. There might not be a single moderation effect (interaction) of either `KB` or `KD` on the `APD` association with your DV, but with a flexible fit you will be able to document how the form of that association differs based on the `KB` and `KD` values.